# how to apply css to dynamic HTML content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, underscore.js

I new to CSS and learning.

My question is,

if at all my HTML content is loaded with with a delay
may be because of an ajax request,
And if I append that html response to the already loaded div tag;

How will I apply CSS to the inner HTML.

let say I have and div tag,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
        <div id="theTableContainer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I am trying to load an html in the div having id "theTableContainer",

I will apply css in the callback function of xhr success after the html is appended to div

as follows

```
$("#theTableContainer table tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq(2)").
            css("background-color","#8600e6").
            css("color","#F8F8FF").
            css("font-weight","bold");
});
```

Is there a better way ?

Please find the link below for the working code.

[My Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/bt2puy76/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to add css classes which you want to add and then use `addClass` to add css dynamically.

```js
$("#theTableContainer table tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td").addClass('background color font-weight');
});
```

```css
.background {
background-color: red;
}

.color {
 color: white;
}

.font-weight {
 font-weight: 'bold';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
        <div id="theTableContainer">
        <table>
         <tr>
         <td>
          example
         </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may always add the style in your css:

```
#theTableContainer table tbody tr td:nth-child(3){
  background-color: #8600e6;
  color: #F8F8FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt2puy76/14/).

An alternative way is based on [grouping the css](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties):

```
$(this).find("td:eq(2)").css({"background-color": "#8600e6", 
                              "color":"#F8F8FF",
                              "font-weight":"bold"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class with all the CSS properties you want:

```
.active {
    background-color: #8600e6;
    color: #F8F8FF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And apply it:

```
$(this).find("td:eq(2)").addClass('active');
```

[Here is jfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bt2puy76/15/)